# Regular expression for Active Directory Password

Tags: c#, regex

Want to confirm and share my ideas with community..

The regular expression for Active Directory passwords should validate that the password

1. is at least six characters in length
2. contains English upper case characters (A through Z)
3. contains English lower case characters (a through z)
4. contains Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
5. contain Non-alphabetic characters ( !, $, #, % ...)
6. Not contain the user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters

The first 5 conditions are simple.

I have found that this should do the work for 1-5 conditions:

```
(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*
```

But how do I add condition 6 — negation of the name and login?

I see it in this way:

First get whatever's forbidden:

```
String enter = fullname + login;

List<string> Negative = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < enter.Length; i += 3)
{
    if (i + 3 > enter.Length)
    {
        enter.Substring(i, 3);
        Negative.Add(enter.Substring(i, 3));
    }

}
```

Then build the regex:

```
StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder("(?=^.{8,255}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))");

foreach(string word in Negative)
{
    pattern.Append("(/^((?!" + word + @")[\s\S])*$/)");
}

pattern.Append("^.*");
```

The pattern should be the required regex now.

My main concern is this line of code:

```
pattern.Append("(/^((?!" + word + @")[\s\S])*$/)");
```

Will it add negative condition for `word`?

Comment: you have `{8,255}` and your 1st requirement is `at least six characters in length`..Also `Non-alphabetic characters` and `alphanumeric characters` becomes `.`..So why use that **huge** regex..

Comment: Anirudh, yep I agree could you provide your version of the code?

Comment: i already had provided the code

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are a great tool, but don't solve everything. E.g., a regular expression can't count in the sense that you require. Yes, a regular expression can count e.g. consecutive letters, but it can't check that you e.g. have two of these and three of the others, spread over the complete input string. This also goes for your specific question. Specifically, checking these two different conditions in the same regular expression may become very difficult.

In this case, I would advise not to use regular expressions and just write a small algorithm that performs all checks. Another advantage you get with this approach, is that mere mortals will be able to understand you algorithm when they revisit it later on. Always an added benefit.

Comment: I agree that it would be easier/clear to split it in few steps. But I need to pass it as the regular expression into third party component. And I disagree that Regex not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your 5th and 1st requirement would result into this regex

```
^.{6,}$
```

For your 6th requirement,

Considering you have an account name as `accountName`

`input` is your target input password

```
bool isNotValid= Regex.Matches(accountName,"(?=(..))")//capturing two consecutive characters of account name
                      .Cast<Match>()
                      .Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value)//two consecutive character's list
                      .Any(y=>input.IndexOf(y)!=-1);
```

Capturing two consecutive characters is as good as capturing more than two consecutive characters

I have used `(?=(..))` to capture two consecutive characters.This would capture `he`,`el`,`ll`,`lo` from hello.